# Perform mathematical operation in two Pandas dataframes using their index value

Tags: pandas

I would like to perform mathmatical operations by index in two dataframes and store into one dataframe. Normally I use numpy and it was fine but with pd dataframe I am getting this error 'Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable'. I have checked shape and len to verify but they they are same for all. The command I have used,

```
df_output.iloc[6,2:] = df_output.iloc[2,2:]*df_pad_Datetime.iloc[3,2:]/1000+ df_output.iloc[6,1:-1]
```

df_output row 6, column starting from 2 to end will be modified with the given condition.
Shape of df_output is (16,542) and
the shape of df_pad_Datetime is (4,542).

df_output.iloc[6,1:-1] suppose to take all the column value starting from 1 to end except the last column for the give row.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few potential issues here. If you consider a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({chr(97 + c): [((r + 1) * (10 ** c)) for r in range(4)] for c in range(3) })
df
```

which gives:

```
    a   b    c
 0  1  10  100
 1  2  20  200
 2  3  30  300
 3  4  40  400
```

If you do a slice on one row and the first two columns it gives a series whose index is the column names of those columns:

```
(s := df.iloc[2,:-1]), type(s)
```

gives

```
(a     3
 b    30
 Name: 2, dtype: int64,
 pandas.core.series.Series)(s
```

If you so a slice on a different ranges of columns it gives a series with a different index:

```
(s := df.iloc[3,1:]), type(s)
```

gives

```
(b     40
 c    400
 Name: 3, dtype: int64,
 pandas.core.series.Series)
```

If you apply an operation on these two series, the operation is applied through the index values. If an index value is present in both series you will get a results, if the index value is only present in one series, you will get a NaN value. The resulting series include the combination of all index values in the two series, so:

```
(series_sum := df.iloc[2,:-1] + df.iloc[3,1:])
```

gives

```
a     NaN
b    70.0
c     NaN
dtype: float64
```

If you try to assign this to a narrower colum selection, you will an error because keys in the indexes are different:

```
df.iloc[1,1:] = series_sum
```

gives:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

However, you can uses the series values, which is a numpy array, and I think this will give you the result you expect:

```
(values_sum := df.iloc[2,:-1].values + df.iloc[3,1:].values)
```

gives

```
array([ 43, 430], dtype=int64)
```

then

```
df.iloc[1,1:] = values_sum
```

gives what I think you are looking for:

```
   a   b    c
0  1  10  100
1  2  43  430
2  3  30  300
3  4  40  400
```

Comment: You did it for a single column all rows but I need it for a single row all columns. I found the problem is this portion (+ df_output.iloc[6,1:-1] ). So using numpy values solves it but no solution in terms of pandas dataframe.

Comment: Ah OK. I think the same issue probably applies though: the rows will have different indexes within so because you're selecting from 3 rows you will end up with three rows in the output all with nans. Sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I have just updated the answer to focus on a single row but multiple columns. I hope this is closer to your original questions.

Comment: Even though I have figured it out your answer is correct so I am accepting it.